# webpack-cli Unable to load '@webpack-cli/serve' command webpack-cli TypeError: devServerFlags is not iterable windows

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, windows-10

I am extreme newb and just realized what webpack was/is doing but I still can not get it to run in my lesson. Here is the error

```
> dev
> webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js

[webpack-cli] Unable to load '@webpack-cli/serve' command
    [webpack-cli] TypeError: devServerFlags is not iterable
        at C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js:28:43
        at WebpackCLI.makeCommand (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:104:31)
        at ServeCommand.apply (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js:10:19)
        at loadCommandByName (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:626:35)
        at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1091:23)
        at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:922:31)
        at Command._parseCommand (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:1503:14)
        at Command.parse (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:1292:10)
        at Command.parseAsync (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:1318:10)
        at WebpackCLI.run (C:\Users\Gamer\code\threejs-dc-1\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1123:28)
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "repository": "#",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config ./bundler/webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.7",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.9",
    "portfinder-sync": "0.0.2",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "three": "^0.126.0",
    "webpack": "^5.24.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  }
}
```

I am running the following:

```
webpack: 5.72.0
webpack-cli: 4.9.2
webpack-dev-server 4.9.0
node v16.15.0
npm 8.5.5
```

on Windows 10.

I have uninstalled (fully) node v18 and npm and reinstalled. I've uninstalled webpack and reinstalled. I am at a loss. Any help is appreciated! I haven't even gotten started on my lesson but I am *learning a lesson* for sure!

Diza

Comment: Also, is there a way I can install and uninstall without having to reboot every dang time?

Comment: [Github discussion here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/2990#issuecomment-937704258)